# Gedit file browser panel does not appear

Tags: xubuntu, gedit

I am currently setting up a new xubuntu setup (using the latest 16.04 iso, because I like to have version parity between my installations) for some short term work, and I ran into a peculiar problem. After installing gedit, the file browser panel does not appear to work. However, I am also not getting any error messages.

Is this a known problem, and if so, does anybody have a workaround? I have another (older) xubuntu install also running 16.04, on which the gedit file browser behaves just fine.

EDIT: I have the file browser enabled in preferences, but when having the side panel open it looks like this:

[image: empty sidebar without file browser icon]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try simply select *View -> Side Panel* (or press <kbd>F9</kbd>) to show *Documents* or *File Browser* in the left. This left side-panel have two modes of operation - *Documents*

[image: Documents]

and *File Browser*.

[image: File Browser]

They are switched by clicking on small arrow [image: arrow] in the right of current label.

---

If this does not help, you can try to reset Gedit settings with

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/gedit/
```

---

Also check Gedit *Preferences* (*Edit -> Preferences*), it should look like:

[image: Gedit Preferences]

---

If it still does not work you can try to reinstall Gedit packages:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gedit gedit-common
```

Comment: See above, I have the file browser enabled in preferences but it wont show up when having the sidebar open.

Comment: You should click on *Documents* and it will switch to *File Manager*, I hope :)